# unexpected T_STRING on first line of code

Tags: php

I have been getting an error saying unexpected T_STRING on line 2 of this script:

```
<? php
session_start();
$incidentKey = $_SESSION['incidentKey'];
$incidentDetailsQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE incidentKey='".$incidentKey."'");
while ($incidentDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($incidentDetailsQuery);
?>
```

And despite looking through the forum heaps, I have had no luck. This was even coming up as an error saying  unexpected T_STRING on line 2 when I the code started like this:

```
<? php
$incidentKey = $_SESSION['incidentKey'];
etc.....
```

I've gone through all other includes and couldn't find any missing terminators leading up to this script. Can anyone think why else I would be getting this error?

Comment: <? php  remove the space to make it <?php

Comment: It's the space after `<? php`. Change it into `<?php`

Comment: Thank's guys, I had no idea that space made a difference!!

Comment: @roullie submit it as an answer so the question is not marked unanswered. user2034544 accept the answer once submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in

```
  <? php
```

to make it

```
  <?php
```